# apostrophe turning into \x92

Tags: python, python-2.7, apostrophe

**mycorpus.txt**

```
Human where's machine interface for lab abc computer applications   
A where's survey of user opinion of computer system response time
```

**stopwords.txt**

```
let's
ain't
there's
```

The following code

```
corpus = set()
for line in open("path\\to\\mycorpus.txt"):
    corpus.update(set(line.lower().split()))
print corpus

stoplist = set()
for line in open("C:\\Users\\Pankaj\\Desktop\\BTP\\stopwords_new.txt"):
    stoplist.add(line.lower().strip())
print stoplist
```

gives the following output

```
set(['a', "where's", 'abc', 'for', 'of', 'system', 'lab', 'machine', 'applications', 'computer', 'survey', 'user', 'human', 'time', 'interface', 'opinion', 'response'])
set(['let\x92s', 'ain\x92t', 'there\x92s'])
```

Why is the apostrophe turning into \x92 in the 2nd set??

Comment: Never use Microsoft's editors if you want to write ASCII's texts. If you want to use them, then you have to handle cp1252(which includes also that "right-quotation mark").

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Code point 92(hex) in window-1252 encoding is Unicode code point 2019(hex) which is 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'. This looks very like an apostrophe and is likely to be the actual character that you have in `stopwords.txt`, which I've guessed from the way python has interpreted in, has be encoded in windows-1252 or an encoding that shares ASCII and `’` codepoint values.

' vs ’

Comment: then in the 1st set why is it showing "where's" instead of 'where\x92s'??

Comment: @PankajSinghal: Probably because you genuinely have the ASCII apostrophe character in the first file. To confirm this use a tool such as hexdump to verify the actual bytes in both of your files.

Comment: ya, i see there's a difference in characters. So what should I do to make it read like "ain't" and not 'ain\x92t' ???

Comment: @PankajSinghal: The simplest thing to do would be to edit `stop words.txt` and replace all `’` with `'` using a text editor or `sed` or similar.